# Is it possible to pass the output of an external command to `:tabnew`?

Tags: vim

I am trying to generate a filename using a shell function and pass it to `tabnew`.

How might I get a working equivalent of the following, where `echo foo` might be replaced by any arbitrary external command?

```
tabnew $(!echo foo)
```

To be clear, the desired result is for the shell command to be evaluated, and its output passed to `tabnew`. In the above example, the command should evaluate to `tabnew foo`.

Comment: @Cyrus, That opens a file with the name `$(echo foo)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this using [`execute`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/28.html) and [`system`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/52.html) to craft a `tabnew` command.

Here is a function you can modify and perhaps stick in your `.vimrc`:

```
function! TabNewFoo()
  execute "tabnew ".system('echo "foo"')
endfunction
```

Invoke with:

```
:call TabNewFoo()
```

---

Or, a more generalized form:

```
function! TabNewFoo(command)
  execute "tabnew ".system(a:command)
endfunction
```

Invoke with:

```
:call TabNewFoo("echo 'foo'")
```

Comment: This looks like it will solve the problem for a specific command. I'll try to generalize this and write up an answer that's more broadly useful.

Comment: @merlin2011 I updated my answer with a more generalized version where you can pass in an ad-hoc command

Comment: Thanks! I think this will be more directly useful for someone else trying to solve the same problem.